# I need help iterating a list of list, To pass through a function

Tags: python, iteration

Ok, What I need to do is iterate through a list of list and for each list parse the results before the iteration starts from the top again. Although the way I tried python made it clear I can't do it my way. So hopefully me showing this will help someone better educate me on how to materialize my theory.

```
list = [['name','phone'],['name2','phone2']](AND SO FORTH)
templist = []
```

Now I'm trying to iterate the 'list' so that I can create a temporary list (templist) so that I can slice the temp list passing it through a function(for each temp list).

ex. templist[0],templist[1]...Then once it passes through the function, I will reset the templist back to empty as the iteration starts back from the top going on to the next list in the 'list'.

here's a sample

```
(insert iteration here):
    foofunction(templist[0],templist[1])
    templist = []
```

Comment: They all worked. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through the list `mylist` and pass the items (which are lists themselves) immediately to `foofunction`:

```
for item in mylist:
    foofunction(*item)
```

The `*` operator is used to unpack the list into multiple parameters to that function (more info can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)).

Comment: Or `itertools.starmap` if you're fancy.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `list` as a variable name. I have renamed your list to `biglist`:

```
biglist = [['name','phone'],['name2','phone2']]

for name, phone in biglist:
    foofunction(name, phone)
```

is equivalent to:

```
foofunction('name', 'phone')
foofunction('name2', 'phone2')
```

Comment: Obviously, this requires that there are always the same number of items in each sublist.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in mylist:
   foofunction(*x)
```